# Плагин Tippy.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Ссылка на сие творение](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/)

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где в этом ... "плагине" хранится `tippy.css` & `tippy.js` или `tippy.min.js` ? В документации про них слово есть, а в репозитории о нем ни слуха ни духа. Или мб какой то особый мануал по подключению существует ? npm'ы, composer'ы и сусосеры - не интересны.

Чисто по стилю старой школы, если можно. Пробовал переходить через веб по исходникам плагина. Копировал, но толку ноль

Answer (score 0):

Upd
Нашел, с горем пополам. Мб кому тоже надо
[Тык](https://unpkg.com/browse/tippy.js@6.1.0/dist/)